# Creating a new results/logging file using paramiko and sftp

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using python and paramiko to read some files using sftp.  The get is working fine.  When I am done processing the file, I would like to put a file summarizing the results.  I would rather not have to save the file locally first in order to do this; I have a dict of the results, I just want to create a file on the sftp server to put that into.  Below is my code, with I hope all of the relevant bits in and the unrelated parts removed for readability.

Note that I am successfully reading the file and processing it, and creating the dict of results, without a problem, and I can print it to my terminal when I run csv_import.  When I try to add the final step of putting the dict of results into a file on the same sftp server, though, it hangs forever.  Any help is appreciated.

```
def csv_import():
we_are_live = True
host = "111.111.111.111"
port = 22
password = "cleverpwd"
username = "cleverun"
t = paramiko.Transport((host,port))
t.connect(username=username, password=password)
if we_are_live and t.is_authenticated():
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
    sftp.chdir('.'+settings.REMOTE_SFTP_DIRECTORY)
    files_to_pick_from = sftp.listdir()
 …file processing code happens here, get back a dictionary of the results...
        results_file_name = 'results'+client_file_name
        results_file = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
        results_file.file(results_file_name,mode='w',bufsize=-1)
        results_file.write(str(sftp_results_of_import))
        results_file.close()
    t.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did something similar a while ago, but i used disk files, maybe you find something useful:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576810-copy-files-over-ssh-using-paramiko/

And if you need to only create files in memory you could try
 StringIO: 
http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

Comment: Code sample helped, thanks!  Didn't end up using StringIO but it also looks valuable to know about.  Much appreciated.